# How to use Dependency Injection with Static Methods?

Tags: dependency-injection, static-methods

Imagine there is a `Customer` class with an instance `Load()` method.

When the `Load()` method is called, it retrieves order details by e.g.

```
var orders = Order.GetAll(customerId, ...);
```

`GetAll()` is a static method of the `Order` class and the input parameters are fields defined in the `Customer` class.

As you can see, `Order` is a dependency of the `Customer` class, however, I can't just create an `IOrder` and inject it there as interfaces can't have static methods.

Therefore, the question is how could I introduce dependency injection in this example?

I don't want to make `GetAll()` an instance method since it's a static method and need to keep it that way.

For example, I have used utility classes in my design, most of which just contain static methods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you *must* keep the static method, I would wrap the static calls in a Repository object.

Like this:

```
interface IOrderRepository {
   IEnumerable<IOrder> GetAll(customerId, ..);
}

class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository {
   IEnumerable<IOrder> GetAll(customerId, ...)
   {
     Order.GetAll(customerId,...); // The original static call.
   }
}
```

Now you inject this repository into your `Customer` class.

(I'm assuming you're doing this so you can inject fake IOrders at runtime for testing purposes.  I should say that in general, static methods are a serious obstacle to testing.)

Comment: Thanks, will these repository classes and interfaces be part of the data access layer? My Order class is a business entity mapped from the Order table (using LINQ to SQL).

Comment: @user133212 it's just a wrapper around your existing function.  so wherever that function logically belongs layer-wise, I would also put the wrapper.

Comment: This seems pointless.  The whole idea is to not have to make an object

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as your aggregate root for fetching orders is your customer model I would *strongly* advise you create a customer repository and inject that to whatever service requires it.

Here is an example:

```java
public class CustomerService
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        if (customerRepository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("customerRepository");
        }

        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IOrder> GetOrdersForCustomerId(int customerId)
    {
        return _customerRepository.GetOrdersForCustomerId(customerId);
    }
}

public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    IEnumerable<IOrder> GetOrdersForCustomerId(int customerId);
}

class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<IOrder> GetOrdersForCustomerId(int customerId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Function Pointer Injection**

TLDR:

Inject a function pointer into the `Customer` class. The value of this function pointer can be `Order.GetAll` in production, and `MockOrder.GetAll` in tests.

EXAMPLE:

The dependency (*problematic static function we depend on*):

```
class Order {
    static func GetAll() -> [Order] {
        var orders = ... // Load from production source
        return orders
    }
}
```

Our dependent class (*depends on static function*):

```
class Customer {
    func Init(getAllOrdersFunction) { // Arg is a func pointer
        self.getAllOrdersFunction = getAllOrdersFunction
    }

    func Load() {
        var orders = self.getAllOrdersFunction()
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Production client class (*performs the dependency injection*):

```
class BusinessLogicManager {
    func DoBusinessLogic() {
        var customer = Customer(Order.GetAll) // Prod func injected here
        customer.Load()
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Testing client class (*how unit test can inject a fake dependency*):

```
class CustomerUnitTests {
    static func GetFakeOrders() {
        var orders = ... // Hardcoded test data
        return orders
    }

    func TestLoad() {
        var customer = Customer(CustomerUnitTests.GetFakeOrders) // Fake func injected here
        customer.Load()
        // Verify results given known behavior of GetFakeOrders
    }
}
```

DISCUSSION:

How you actually inject the "function pointer" will depend on the syntax and features available in your language. Here I'm just talking about the general concept.

This isn't exactly a pretty solution. It would probably be easier if you can change `GetAll` to be an instance method (perhaps by introducing an `OrdersLoader` object, or by using Paul Phillips' answer). But if you really want to keep it as a static function, then this solution will work.