# Call another class static method results in coupling

Tags: oop

In OOP we don't want coupling of classes. If I want to use an instance of class b within class a I can use dependency injection.

However if I want to use static methods of class b within class a  I dont see any option but to "require" or "import" class b in the class a class file. This ends up with coupling between the classes - going against OOP principles. But the alternative is to rewrite the static method of class b as a static method in class a - going against the DRY principle. What is the right way?

This question was flagged as a possible duplicate of [How to use Dependency Injection with Static Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523463/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-static-methods) but I feel that my question is asking from a more generic perspective on using another class' static methods. The think the question and accepted answer in the possible duplicate is more specific to a use case, but would not apply for example to a mere utility static method in the external class. My question aims to seek answer from a general oop perspective.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Dependency Injection with Static Methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523463/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-static-methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety options here and the specific use case is important in deciding what you may want to do. So, the big three would be...

- Migrate the static method off Class B and into a shared library class, which is purely a holder for static methods and is never instantiated (in Java you'd make the constructor `private` and the class `final`). Then both class A and class B can access the method without depending on each other and without violating the DRY principle and the dependency on the library class is no better nor worse than relying on a static method defined on the same class.
- If you're talking about a static method which is really something that best lives on class B then you can hide that method call behind some kind of a provider instance which is dependency injected into class A, with the provider implementation simply calling the static method on B. If you wanted to be really evil then the provider could also be injected into instances of B, but that would probably be overkill.
- The static method can be changed to be an instance method on a new class which is dependency injected into both A and B. Sometimes this has a side-benefit of allowing you to hide some state in the instance rather than having to pass parameters into an otherwise stateless method.

Note that static methods in general cause problems in OO terms so only really the third options is a 'clean' one that really decouples classes and properly allow for coding to interfaces.

Comment: Im a little unsure on the 2nd point - the "provider instance". What would this look like? And wouldnt this result in tight coupling between the provider instance class and class B?

Comment: Yes, very much so, the provider would be tightly coupled to class B. You could reflect the reality of that in a few different ways - you could hide the provider behind a static factory method, for example. The key is to bear in mind that the goal is to decouple A & B, not to decouple all classes (which is fundamentally impossible). Something somewhere really does need to know what your implementation involves - the key is to keep application logic (object use) separate from configuration (object creation).