# How to propagate object reference change?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am building a Windows Forms application that displays a MessageBox from time to time using the static MessageBox.Show() method.

I wrapped the static call in a Repository object, as shown in this question: [How to use Dependency Injection with Static Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523463/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-static-methods)

In the MainClass, this Repository object uses the original static call by default, but the MainClass also provides a method SetMessageBoxRepoDependency() that sets this Repository object. This opens up options for dependency injection. One use of this is to use a mocking tool to reference the Repository interface, and teach the mocked Show method not to create a real MessageBox during testing.

However, the MainClass also creates a number of other objects that use this Repository instance. How can I modify my code so that when MainClass's SetMessageBoxRepoDependency() is called, the other objects will also use the new Repository?

(I can modify MainClass's constructor to take in a custom Repository, but would like to know how the Repository can be set after MainClass has been created)

**MainClass**

```
public class MainClass
{
    private IMessageBoxRepository messageBoxRepo;

    public MainClass()
    {
        messageBoxRepo = new MessageBoxRepository();

        // Just classes that reference the same Repository
        var classA = new ClassA(messageBoxRepo);
        var classB = new ClassB(messageBoxRepo);
        var classC = new ClassC(messageBoxRepo);
    }

    public void SetMessageBoxRepoDependency(IMessageBoxRepository messageBoxRepo)
    {
        this.messageBoxRepo = messageBoxRepo;
    }
}
```

**MessageBoxRepository**

```
public class MessageBoxRepository : IMessageBoxRepository
{
    public DialogResult Show(string text)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(text); // The original static call.
    }
}
```

**IMessageBoxRepository**

```
public interface IMessageBoxRepository
{
    DialogResult Show(string text);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't smell like "dependency-injection" at all. with all the "new" key word there, there is no dependency injection at all, you need a container class to manage your Object and their lifecycle and replace all your new ClassXXX() with container.Resolve<IInterface> if you MainClass is your composite root.

Comment: @LeY I don't think the class should be calling the `container.Resolve<>()`, it should be passed via constructor like every other class.

Comment: this `messageBoxRepo = new MessageBoxRepository();` is not DI...

Comment: @LeY, if `MainClass` is an entry point of application then it is correct place to use `new` for building application's object graph. Notice that Dependency Injection don't requires frameworks or container. Container is implementation details of DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd want your DI Container to sort of *run* things:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var container = GetContainer();

            // most likely the only resolve you need.
            var form = container.Resolve<Form1>();

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(form);
        }

        private static IContainer GetContainer()
        {
           // Register Dependencies
           // Build the Container
           // return Container;
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you're using Autofac (I don't know about other frameworks, but they should be able to do the same), any form should be able to change it's constructor signature to a `Func<>` to resolve new instances per invoke:

```
public class Form1
{
  private Func<IMessageBoxRepository> _mbr;

  public Form1(Func<IMessageBoxRepository> mbr)
  {
    _mbr = mbr;
  }

  public void OnError(string msg)
  {
    var mb = _mbr();
    mb.Show(msg);
  }
}
```

This means you don't have to expose your container all over the place (which you shouldn't have to, especially if you plan on unit testing).

Unit testing then becomes pretty easy (example assumes NSubstitute, but hey all do something similar):

```
public class Form1Test
{
  public void OnError_WithAny_CallsShow()
  {
    // Arrange
    var mbr = Substitute.For<IMessageBoxRepository>();
    var mbrFunc = Substitute.For<Func<IMessageBoxRepository>>();
    mbrFunc().Returns(mbr);
    var form1 = new Form1(mbrFunc);

    // Act
    form1.OnError(null);

    // Assert
    mbr.Received().Show();
  }
}
```