# How can I use DI for 3'rd party static class in Dot Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Someone in our company wrote (*by mistake, a long time ago*) this static class, being served from Nuget : (I can't edit it)

```
public static class MailService
 {

    public static void SendEmail(string recipients, string subject, string msg  )
    {
        SendEmail(recipients, subject,  msg);
    }
...
}
```

I already know it's bad. But let's continue.
I want to use this class via DI in my asp.net core project.
Problem is that I can't use this (because `static` can't be new'ed):

```
  services.AddSingleton<MailService>();
```

[image]

**Question:**

Is there still a way to make `MailService` (or any wrapper for it ) Injectable?

Comment: I think this is somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523463/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-static-methods ?

Comment: Can't you wrap it in a custom class/interface (such as `MailSender`/`IMailSender`)? Call `MailService` in `MailSender` and inject `IMailSender` whenever you'll need `MailService`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```cs
public interface IMailService {
    void SendEmail(string recipients, string subject, string msg);
}

public class MailServiceWrapper : IMailService {
    public void SendEmail(string recipients, string subject, string msg) {
        MailService.SendEmail(recipients, subject, msg);
    }
}
```

And in the Startup class:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMailService, MailServiceWrapper>();
```